# Java server- Android socket connection

Tags: android, sockets

My goal is to create Java application which would be server, and Android(client) socket connection, and make Android phone listen to my commands send from a server. My question is, how should i make my Android phone always listen for incoming commands(Strings) pushed from Java application. What is a best choice ? Thread, Service ?

Here is my code : Server in java:

```
public class Server extends JFrame {

    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextArea chatWindow;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    // private DataInputStream input;
    private Socket connection;
    ServerSocket server;

    public Server() {
        super("GUI");
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setEditable(false);
        userText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sendMessage(e.getActionCommand());
                userText.setText("");

            }
        });
        add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300, 150);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    // connect to server
    public void startRunning() {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(9000, 100);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    waitForConnection();
                    setupStreams();
                    whileChatting();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (EOFException e) {
            showMessage("\n Connection lost");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeCrap();
        }
    }

    // connect to server
    private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
        showMessage(" \nWaiting for connection \n");
        connection = server.accept();
        showMessage(" now connected to  "
                + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }

    private void setupStreams() throws IOException {
        showMessage("\n Setting up streams \n");
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        // input = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        showMessage(" Streams are good \n");

    }

    private void whileChatting() throws IOException {
        ableToType(true);
        String message = "You are now connected ";
        sendMessage(message);
        do {// have conversation
            try {
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                // message = (String) input.readLine();
                showMessage("\n" + message);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                showMessage("Dont know that object type ");

                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        } while (!message.equals("server - end"));
    }

    // close everything
    private void closeCrap() {
        showMessage("\n Closing..");
        ableToType(false);
        try {
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // send message to server
    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        try {
            output.writeObject("CLIENT - " + message);
            output.flush();
            showMessage("\n" + "CLIENT - " + message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            chatWindow.append("\n Smth is wrong sending message");
        }

    }

    private void showMessage(final String m) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                chatWindow.append(m);
            }
        });
    }

    private void ableToType(final boolean tof) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userText.setEditable(tof);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Android Client code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView text;
    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream is;
    DataOutputStream os;
    public final String TAG = "CLIENT";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        ConnectThread thread = new ConnectThread();
        thread.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class ConnectThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        public ConnectThread() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG,"Do in background");
            return connect();

        }

        public String connect() {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG," creating socket");
                socket = new Socket("192.168.1.10", 9000);
                Log.i(TAG," socket created");
                os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Log.i(TAG," Streams are set");
                Log.i(TAG,"::"+is.readUTF().toString());
                text.setText(is.readLine().toString());
                return is.readLine().toString();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("fail", e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("fail", e.toString());
            }
            return "nothing";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without having more info on what you're trying to do, I'd say that your best solution is a background service that dispatches a separate thread with your socket on it. What have you tried so far? Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: When you use a thread, your app needs to be open. If you use a service, that is independent from the app start. You can let the service run allways. Is a bad idea when dealing with network. Periodic access is better. Think about the data and actions you want to perform and then decide who will be the server and the client and how you can decrease the impact on the battery of the phone

Comment: This is important: https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html

Comment: The idea of application, is to get List of calls from Android phone by sending one command form java aplication, or more specifically. I send a request from java, phone sends my requested data.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. Im sending messages from my java server to android trough a socket, and android is always listening. Here is my code: 
Java :

```
public class Server extends JFrame {

    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextArea chatWindow;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    // private DataInputStream input;
    private Socket connection;
    ServerSocket server;

    public Server() {
        super("GUI");
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setEditable(false);
        userText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sendMessage(e.getActionCommand());
                userText.setText("");

            }
        });
        add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300, 150);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    // connect to server
    public void startRunning() {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(9000, 100);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    waitForConnection();
                    setupStreams();
                    whileChatting();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (EOFException e) {
            showMessage("\n Connection lost");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeCrap();
        }
    }

    // connect to server
    private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
        showMessage(" \nWaiting for connection \n");
        connection = server.accept();
        showMessage(" now connected to  "
                + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }

    private void setupStreams() throws IOException {
        showMessage("\n Setting up streams \n");
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        // input = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        showMessage(" Streams are good \n");

    }

    private void whileChatting() throws IOException {
        ableToType(true);
        String message = "You are now connected ";
        sendMessage(message);
        do {// have conversation
            try {
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                // message = (String) input.readLine();
                showMessage("\n" + message);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                showMessage("Dont know that object type ");

                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        } while (!message.equals("server - end"));
    }

    // close everything
    private void closeCrap() {
        showMessage("\n Closing..");
        ableToType(false);
        try {
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // send message to server
    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        try {
            output.writeUTF("CLIENT - " + message);
            output.flush();
            showMessage("\n" + "CLIENT - " + message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            chatWindow.append("\n Smth is wrong sending message");
        }

    }

    private void showMessage(final String m) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                chatWindow.append(m);
            }
        });
    }

    private void ableToType(final boolean tof) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userText.setEditable(tof);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And android :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView text;
    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream is;
    ObjectOutputStream os;
    public final String TAG = "CLIENT";

    Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        handler = new Handler();
        Thread x = new Thread(new ClientThread());
        x.start();
        handler = new Handler();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //
    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        public ClientThread() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                while (true) {
                    socket = new Socket("192.168.1.10", 9000);

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            text.setText("Connected.");
                            try {
                                os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                text.setText("Output stream. smth wrong");
                                Log.i(TAG, "Output stream. smth wrong");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = in.readUTF()) != null) {
                            Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                            final String mesg = line;
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO THE FRONT END
                                    // THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN BE CREATIVE
                                    text.append(mesg + "\n");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                text.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception x) {
            }
        }

    }

}
```